# Adding the appropriate column and row means to each element of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, mds

I have a newbie question, sorry for that. I am doing the metric [multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) step-by-step in R. Therefore, I have to compute the following:

b<sub>rs</sub> = a<sub>rs</sub> - mean(a<sub>r</sub>) - mean(a<sub>s</sub>) + mean(a)

I tried it with this code but of course it delivers correct results only for the diagonale:

```
i <- c(1:5)
j <- c(1:5)    
brs <- (A[i,j] - colMeans(A[i,]) - rowMeans(A[,j]) + mean(A))
```

FYI:

```
A <- matrix(c(0,-40.5,-8,-50,-24.5,-10.5,0,-4.5,-0.5,-2,-8,-4.5,0,-32,-18,-50,-0.5,-32,0,-12.5,-24.5,-2,-18,-12.5,0),nrow=5)
```

The result should be a matrix with the following values:

```
B <- matrix(c(33.8,-21.8,13.7,-21.8,-3.9,-21.8,3.6,2.1,12.6,3.5,13.7,2.1,9.6,-15.9,-9.5,-21.8,12.6,-15.9,22.6,2.5,-3.9,3.5,-9.5,2.5,7.4),nrow=5)
```

Comment: You get the same values for `colMeans(A[i,])` and `colMeans(A[,j])`.  I think you don't need i, j, etc

Comment: But not always?! When I want to have B[1,3] I need the mean of column 1 and the mean of row 3. This isn't the same value. Or do I understand wrongly?!

Comment: I am not able to get the values in B.  Could you show how you got 33.8 from A's values

Comment: I also don't get them but I want to get them (I know that B is the correct solution). With my R code I get the following values for B: 33.8 -36.9   1.6 -27.4 -17.1  -6.7   3.6   5.1  22.1   5.4  25.8  -0.9   9.6  -9.4 -10.6 -16.2   3.1 -22.4  22.6  -5.1   9.3   1.6  -8.4  10.1   7.4 (so, only the values in the diagonale are correct).

Comment: I am not sure if the formula is correct.  I double checked the values and it is not the same output

Comment: Hm, another question: How would you code the formula brs = ars - mean(ar) - mean(as) + mean(a) in R?

Comment: I would use `A- rowMeans(A)[row(A)] - colMeans(A)[col(A)] + mean(A)` and I am getting 29 instead of 33.8 for the first value

Comment: Unfortunately, 33.8 has to be correct, It is an example of a textbook and when I do it by hand/my calculator manually, I also get 33.8... :(

Comment: Are you sure that the formula is correct. If you calculate it for `A[1,1]` you get 29

`A[1,1] - rowMeans(A)[1] - colMeans(A)[1] + mean(A)`